# How to replace all characters in a string using JavaScript for this specific case: replace . by _

Tags: javascript, regex

The following statement in JavaScript works as expected:

```
var s1 = s2.replace(/ /gi, '_'); //replace all spaces by the character _
```

However, to replace all occurrences of the character . by the character _, I have:

```
var s1 = s2.replace(/./gi, '_');
```

But the result is a string entirely filled with the character _

Why and how to replace . by _ using JavaScript?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The . character in a regex will match everything.  You need to escape it, since you want a literal period character:

```
var s1 = s2.replace(/\./gi, '_');
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to escape the dot, since it's a special character in regex

```
s2.replace(/\./g, '_');
```

Note that dot doesn't require escaping in character classes, therefore if you wanted to replace dots and spaces with underscores in one go, you could do:

```
s2.replace(/[. ]/g, '_');
```

Using `i` flag is irrelevant here, as well as in your first regex.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use strings instead of regular expressions.

```
var s1 = s2.replace ('.', '_', 'gi')
```

Comment: +1 Good point - regex is overkill here. (cue the J.Z. quote in 3...2...1...)

Comment: The 3rd parameter is not standard. Not all browser will support it. See this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 3):

There is also this that works well too :

```
var s1 = s2.split(".").join("_"); // Replace . by _ //
```

Comment: that's a very strange approach

Comment: well, it's the only one that doesn't require RegExp at all.

Comment: This is a different approach, its better that replace which replaces the first occurrence only

Answer (score 0):

if need replace  "  to backspace with "
value.replace(/"/g, '\"')