# Replace all letters in a word to * in js

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I need to create a javascript function that replaces all letters of a word to an asterisk `*` .It should replace the word `hello123` to `********`. How can this be done ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why 5 letters and 3 digits get replaced by 3 asterixes?

Comment: @EugenRieck: It was a formatting issue. Markdown uses asterisk to delimit italics.

Comment: You mean something like `s.replace(/./g, '*')` ?

Comment: If this is meant to hide the actual input (like a password input field) on a webpage, just use `<input type="password"/>`, instead of text input. No script required.

Comment: It can be done like this without `.replace()`, too: `Array(word.length + 1).join('*')`

Answer (score 34):

Use `str.replace(...)`.

Many examples on the interwebs :-D

For example:

```
str.replace('foo', 'bar');
```

Or in your case:

```
str.replace(/./g, '*');
```

Comment: Agree - no more information needed.

Comment: Hi Neal, this *is* the interwebs. Maybe an example is in order.

Comment: Yep, your first example was inapplicable, thanks for adding a working one - it sets a good example for other posters who aren't as experienced as you are on this site, and helps people who aren't experienced in javascript.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I thought id add a `foo` -> `bar` case so that you get the general idea.

Answer (score 9):

You can just do:

```
'hello123'.replace(/./g, '*');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this link
[How to replace all characters in a string using JavaScript for this specific case: replace . by _](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103056/how-to-replace-all-characters-in-a-string-using-javascript-for-this-specific-cas)

```
var s1 = s2.replace(/\S/gi, '*');
```

which will replace anything but whitespace or

```
var s1 = s2.replace(/./gi, '*');
```

which will replace every single character to `*` even whitespace