# Replace all characters in specific group to asterisks

Tags: javascript, regex

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825829/replace-all-letters-in-a-word-to-in-js) SO post that is close, but I want to expand on this question a bit.

I need to replace each character (within a group of the regex) to an asterisk. For example

`Hello, my password is: SecurePassWord` => `Hello, my password is: **************`

I have a regex to grab it into groups, but I can't figure out how to apply this example (from link): `str.replace(/./g, '*');`

to something like this: `str.replace(/(Hello, my password is\: )(\w+)/g, '$1...');` where the `...` would be the magic to convert the characters from $2 to asterisks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) with `String.prototype.replace` which will get the matching text and groups.

```js
var input = 'Hello, my password is: SecurePassWord';
var regex = /(Hello, my password is: )(\w+)/;
var output = input.replace(regex, function(match, $1, $2) {
  // $1: Hello, my password is: 
  // $2: SecurePassWord
  // Replace every character in the password with asterisks
  return $1 + $2.replace(/./g, '*');
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you don't especially need regex.

With :

```
var password = "something";
```

You can do :

```
var mystring = "My passsword is " + Array(password.length).join("*");
```

Or :

```
var mystring = "My passsword is " + password;
mystring = mystring.replace(password, Array(password.length).join("*"));
```