# replace characters with asterisk react input

Tags: reactjs

I want to replace all number values in my React component with asterisk sign on input but just can't seem to get it right. As soon as user types character on input then it must display as asterisk sign.

I tried using the replace method but just can't seem to get it to work.

Is it possible to add function to onChange to replace all characters with asterisk sign?

Comment: Add the code of whatever you have attempted so far.

Comment: You can just use `input type='password'` to receive asterisks. And then you can toggle on and off the type between text and password

Comment: @SebastianBerglönn type password is not going to work as it will change the characters of the current input, i want the character to be replaced by asterisk sign onchange

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by CSS, as you have not mentioned what approach is needed, so I will send this example. hope it will be helpful

```css
input[type="text"] { -webkit-text-security: none; }
input[type="text"] { -webkit-text-security: circle; }
input[type="text"] { -webkit-text-security: square; }
input[type="text"] { -webkit-text-security: disc; /* Default */ }
```

```html
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="blabla..."/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Amir-Mousavi I like this approach but unfortunately it does the same as changing input type to password. I want the onChange to run function which changes text to asterisk character.

Comment: aha, if I guessed right you want input like some mobile UIs to show the real value for a fraction of a second then replace it with an asterisk ?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/793/  not 100% what you want but good start to know about field masking

Comment: nope still not updating state, should be able to run function to do this, just not sure how to implement it

Comment: your question is not clear at all, you want the value in the state be `*` ? you do not care what users input is, just to the count of characters inserted, have `*` in the sate?

Comment: you are not understanding correctly. the input should be clear but the render onchange should display masked text. i do not want to add masking on the input field, only where it is rendering. here is example which might give you better understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021692/replace-all-characters-in-specific-group-to-asterisks